# Does the Gokhale Method improve spine-related medical conditions?

Tags: medical-science

Acupuncturist and author, Esther Gokhale promotes (e.g. [TEDx Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1luKAS_Xcg)) the [Gokhale Method](http://gokhalemethod.com/gokhale-method) for preventing back-pain by adopting encouraging better posture.

> The Gokhale Method uses healthy posture and movement to help you regain your structural integrity and regain a pain-free life.
>
> [...]
>
> We can re-learn what we once knew:
>
> - Our ancestors knew how to move without pain.
> - Babies know how to move without pain.
> - Some cultures still know how to move without pain.

The web-site promises to help with a range of problems, including lower back pain, knee pain, neck pain, bursitis, headaches, RSI, sciatica, scoliosis, etc.

It is apparently based on the observation that indigenous people do not suffer back pain, but carry themselves in a posture with a "j-shaped spine".

Is there any evidence that the Gokhale Method improves any of the listed problems?